# Winium Automation in Java. How can I press the letters in my keyboard like letter "Y"?

Tags: testing, automation

Here's the list of commands that I've tried but still it didn't work.

```
    driver.findElement(By.name("3")).sendKeys("Y");
    driver.findElement(By.name("3")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+"\u0059");

    driver.findElement(By.name("3")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+"Y");


    driver.findElement(By.name("3")).sendKeys(String.valueOf('\u0059'));
    driver.findElement(By.name("3")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "Y" + Keys.CONTROL);
    driver.findElement(By.name("3")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL).sendkeys();




  driver.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(String.valueOf('\u0061')).perform();

    String selectAll = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "Y");
    driver.findElement(By.name("3")).sendKeys(selectAll);
    driver.findElement(By.name("3")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "Y"));
    driver.findElement(By.name("3")).submit();
    driver.findElement(By.name("3")).sendKeys(Keys.valueOf("Y"));
```

I Just want to press one letter or multiple letters from my keyboard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by using this command. Though this one is from robot library.

```
 import java.awt.AWTException;
 import java.awt.Robot;

 Robot rb = new Robot();
 rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Y);
```

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if that's relevant in your situation at all but just keep in mind that the Robot library will be problematic if you need to run it on headless machine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to fill data in a text area using selenium?

then you could use,

```
 driver.FindElement(By.XPath("String")).sendKeys("y");
```

or to press any key,

```
char c = '025'; // ASCII code y
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("String")).SendKeys(Convert.ToString(c));
```

i think this will work.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but it didn't work.  char c = '025' has an error .change type c to string. I also don't have xpath so I can only use findelement by name. I just want to press the letter on my keyboard. I don't need to fill the data in a text area.